# How to check if a user installed my app from my another app? iOS (Unity)

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I have 2 apps and I want to know if in my app 1, the app 2 is installed (and in my app 2, check if my app 1 is installed).

I know the function :
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]`

But the problem is I have to add the urls scheme in `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in my Info.plist but maybe tomorrow I want to develop a third application and I don't want to rebuild all my apps and include my new url scheme inside my application 1 and 2.

Is it possible to check if an user has one of my application by the developer ID or something like that? Without rebuild new version of my apps just for adding 1 url scheme when I release a new app?

Thank you

Comment: You can make web service, where you apps will report their's `identifierForVendor`. You can add login option. May be you can find something useful in Game Center.

Answer (score 1):

You can have all your apps use the same "App Group" (google more information on how to set it up, it's easy) and you can create a `NSUserDefaults` suite using that group identifier.

On launch, each app could write the `Appname Installed` key to that `NSUserDefaults` suite and since it's a shared suite between your apps, others could read the value and know if `Appname` is installed.

The downside of this is that there's no way for your app to know when it's being uninstalled, so if it's installed once the key will show up there even if the app was removed.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is using URL schemes. Each of your app should register a URL scheme it can handle, and then from the other app you call [canOpenURL(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl) on `UIApplication` to test if your app is installed.

Example:

If you have MyApp1 which has registered the URL scheme `myapp1://`, from your other app you can:

`UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "myapp1://")!)`

Pay special attention to the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` key you need to add to your Info.plist. This is needed for this to work and is mentioned on the documentation page I linked above.

Contrary to the application group approach, this will correctly identify when your app is uninstalled.

Comment: Yes I know, but my question is how to avoid to add the new url scheme in `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`? I don't want to rebuild the app each time I want to create a new app